# LINQ to SQL trouble

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

i have following trouble with LINQ to SQL entities:

```
// Context is DataContext that was auto genereted when i create my .dbml file

var cl = Context.Classes.ToArray();
var rm = Context.Rooms.ToArray();

List<DaySchedule> s = new List<DaySchedule>();
s.Add(new DaySchedule()
    {
        Class = cl[0],
        DayOfWeek = 0,
        Pair = 1,
        Room = rm[0]
    });
Context.SubmitChanges();
```

so, after "SubmitChanges" new DaySchedules will be saved to db. BUT i didn't call InsertOnSubmit function and i don't want to save this DaySchedule.

BTW, 
if i will using following code:

```
s.Add(new Acceron.University.DBAccess.DaySchedule()
    {
        Class_id = cl[0].Class_ID,
        DayOfWeek = 0,
        Pair = 1,
        Room_id = rm[0].Room_ID
    });
```

It will not be auto saved to db.

Could you explain is it bug or feature and how i can solve it?

Comment: The first code snippet won't even work, as you're using `c` and `r` which I *suspect* should be `cl` and `rm`.

Comment: of course, sry changed in the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is by design.  Class and Room are context-aware entities,  since they were queried against the context.  Anytime a context-aware entity adds children, it queues up those changes automatically to the context and marks it as inserted.  So you cannot add new entities without the auto-queuing feature.  I'd highly recommend not calling save changes later on.

Comment: +1 If you don't want to save changes, don't called `SaveChanges`.